# Unable to load images/files pisa pdf Django python

Tags: python, django, pisa

I had a problem before where it wouldn't show Chinese characters even when I specified `@font-face` to use a UTF-8 font. It turns out I cannot display images as well... so I seems like I am unable to get any of the files embeded into my pdf.

This is the code I use:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    """Function to render html template into a pdf file"""
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")),
                                            dest=result,
                                            encoding='UTF-8',
                                            link_callback=fetch_resources)
    if not pdf.err:
        response = http.HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')

        return response

    return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))

def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    import os.path
    from django.conf import settings
    path = os.path.join(
            settings.STATIC_ROOT,
            uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ""))
    return path
```

html

```
<img src="/static/images/bc_logo_bw_pdf.png" />
```

and

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Wingdings";
        src: url("/static/fonts/wingdings.ttf");
    }
```

I looked at the other quests on SO but it was no help. There are also no exceptions happening in the two functions. Also in `fetch_resources` function the path returned was the correct full path to the file i.e. `/home/<user>/project/static/images/bc_logo_bw_pdf.png` and `/home/<user>/project/static/fonts/wingdings.ttf` and I am at a loss as to what is wrong.

**UPDATE**
Everytime I create a pdf, I get this message on the console

```
No handlers could be found for logger "ho.pisa"
```

could this be related?

**UPDATE #2**

The font works now I made a dumb mistake... The font I was using did not have the Chinese unicode. But I still cannot embed any images onto the pdf, be it jpeg, gif or png.

Comment: Are you sure your font really has Chinese characters? Fount could be unicode but still lacking some characters.

Comment: `logger` issue is unrelated (and harmless)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The fonts work now, but the image still does not work

Comment: zentenk, I see that my code helps to you. Don't forget vote up my post on your previous answer ;) Also, let to you that: 1) this code works for me and is tested with images. 2) after wasting a lot of time with Pisa I have move my reports to [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html)

Comment: I think you should once try with jpg image file.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally solved the problem I was having... it turns out it doesn't work if I set the `body`'s height with css... once I removed that line the image was loading perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

For me (django 1.4, python 2.7 pisa==3.0.33), If I put the full path of image instead of relative, it works for me. 
Try doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks better . Try once with JPG image file.  In my case PNG file was also not working.

```
<img src="/static/images/<name>.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

without `width` and `height` attribute image will not work. add width and height attribute.

```
<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="image" width="200" height="150" />
```

this fix works for me.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem here. Don't give up with XHTML2PDF Pisa.
 
Pisa use PIL for generate PDF and use lib zip decoder to inserting images.
You should check if your PIL already installed properly with zip decoder, fonts and several components

I have solve this problem by installing PIL with zip decoder.
http://obroll.com/install-python-pil-python-image-library-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

If you need more detail information, you can read my article here :
http://obroll.com/how-to-load-images-files-style-css-in-pdf-using-pisa-xhtml2pdf-on-django/