# html to pdf using pisa- Issue with using img tag

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I want to create a dynamic pdf using html in google app engine. Im using pisa to convert html to pdf. Everything except < img > tag works. Even though the background-image in the css works my real need is the < img > tag.

```
import os
import urllib
import unicodedata
import logging
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from pdf_libs.pisa.ho import pisa

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=mlskdf.pdf'
    html = """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
        margin-top:1.8cm;
        margin-bottom: 1cm;
        background-image: url('logo.jpg');
        @frame footer {
        -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
        bottom: 0.5cm;
        margin-left: 0.75cm;
        margin-right: 0.75cm;
        height: 1cm;
        }
        @frame header {
        -pdf-frame-content: headerContent;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        top: 0.2cm;
        margin-left: 0.75cm;
        margin-right: 0.75cm;
        height: 2cm;
        }
        }
        .footer .head
        {
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:4;
            width:100%;
        }
        table {
        -pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: shrink;
        }
        h1 {
            page-break-before:always;
        }

        div.invoice_header {
        background-color: black;
        color: #FFF;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        text-align: center;
        }

        div.address_field {
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu';
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right:450px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="invoice_header">
        <label align="center" >
            <font face="Ubuntu" size="16">
                HEADER
            </font>
        </label>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="address_field" >
           Another field
    </div>
    <table width="100%" height="100px" border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="50%"><font face="Ubuntu" size="24">column1</font></td>
            <td width="25%"><font face="Ubuntu" size="4">column2</font></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br/></br>
    <div id="footerContent">
          <div class="footer">
        This is footer.. Page <pdf:pagenumber/>
          </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>"""
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(html, self.response.out)
    logging.info(pdf)



 application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', MainHandler)
    ],debug=True)**
```

When i add the < img > tag, i get the following error

```
ERROR    2014-08-06 04:53:25,903 pisa_document.py:223] Document error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/pisa/sx/pisa3/pisa_document.py", line 172, in pisaDocument
    doc.build(c.story)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 877, in build
    self.handle_flowable(flowables)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 762, in handle_flowable
    if frame.add(f, canv, trySplit=self.allowSplitting):
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/frames.py", line 174, in _add
    flowable.drawOn(canv, self._x + self._leftExtraIndent, y, _sW=aW-w)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 106, in drawOn
    self._drawOn(canvas)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 87, in _drawOn
    self.draw()#this is the bit you overload
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/pisa/sx/pisa3/pisa_reportlab.py", line 575, in draw
    Paragraph.draw(self)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py", line 970, in draw
    self.drawPara(self.debug)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py", line 1436, in drawPara
     dpl( tx, offset, lines[0], noJustifyLast and nLines==1)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py", line 307, in _leftDrawParaLineX
     _putFragLine(offset, tx, line)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/platypus/paragraph.py", line 216, in _putFragLine
     tx._canvas.drawImage(cbDefn.image,cur_x_s,cur_y+iy0,w,h,mask='auto')
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py", line 825, in drawImage
    imgObj = pdfdoc.PDFImageXObject(name, image, mask=mask)
  File "/home/developer/Dropbox/File Tx Ganadev/new_project_template/pdf_libs/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py", line 2076, in __init__
    ext = string.lower(os.path.splitext(source)[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 105, in splitext
    return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, altsep, extsep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 91, in _splitext
    sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
 AttributeError: PmlImage instance has no attribute 'rfind'
 ERROR    2014-08-06 04:53:25,911 webapp2.py:1528] PmlImage instance has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code? Or with the img tag? The error is telling you that you're trying to get an attribute 'rfind' that doesn't exist on the PmlImage instance

Comment: I think this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959622/unable-to-load-images-files-pisa-pdf-django-python Couple years ago, I drop PISA for xhtml2pdf.

Comment: @Gwell Could the error be caused by any directory setting. I had some difficulty installing PIL and other dependencies. I somehow managed to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Pillow library to requirements.txt file?
Please add following code to requirements.txt file:

```
Pillow==2.0.0
xhtml2pdf==0.2.1.
```

This is some of my code.

```
import unicodedata
import StringIO
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
.......
packet = StringIO.StringIO()
pisa.CreatePDF(source_html, dest=packet)
.......
```

After convert you can get using packet.getvalue() and return it front-end.